# How to rename the table persistent_logins in Spring-Security

Tags: spring, security, authentication, remember-me

The default table name that manages remember-me authentication in Spring Security is "persistent_logins".

Due to Database naming conventions, I need to rename this table "**persistent_logins**" to "**T_PERSISTENT_LOGINS**".

Any help please.

Comment: In Ecuador, South America, many developers think that prefixing a SQL table name with **T_** is a naming standard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to write your own implementation of [JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/4.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl.java/)

Create a class extending JdbcDaoSupport and implementing PersistentTokenRepository

Configure this class as a bean in your Spring Application Context Config, then set it as the token-repository-ref attribute of the remember-me Spring Security Config

But frankly, I'd change your table naming policy first.

Comment: This make sense if the table  "**persistent_logins**" is going to be in a different schema