# persistent_logins in Spring-Security

Tags: spring, security

How to rename the table persistent_logins in Spring-Security?

[How to rename the table persistent_logins in Spring-Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261216/how-to-rename-the-table-persistent-logins-in-spring-security)

I found one solution, but it’s not clear there. Who can show how to do this?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?